# how can I fix the (broken) icons in the notification area upon login?

Tags: 10.04, nvidia

The icons in the notification area are sometimes broken upon login. This is always fixed if I close the session and login again.

See in this [screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/20a81fac16.png), the usual "power" button is replaced by a part of my user name. The whole username should be "agustin".

The problem is not just visual, if you click where the power button should be you get no functionality. Interestingly, if you click on the other button, and you move the cursor qith the arrow keys, you get the menu.

I believe this problem is related to the nvidia propietary drivers, but I am not sure. Any ideas? Anyone had this problem like me?

--
Agustín

Comment: There's a related question and discussion here: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/374/why-do-my-clock-indicator-applets-and-notification-area-sometimes-move-around-w .  Some of the answers offered there may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`killall gnome-panel`

The panel will disappear, but don't panic... it will reappear in a few seconds with all your icons in place.

Comment: *Most* of the icons. Some apps are fussy and wont re-add themselves (xchat for one)

Comment: thanks! is there a way to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas/27

I added the repository with sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates, updated aptitude and then got some new updates in update manager, mainly about nvida and the new driver.

This new driver solved my problems, I'm not sure on how stable or experimental these packages are, but they seem pretty good to me.

--
Agustín

Comment: nope, the drivers are better, but it's not a solution.